# Ethereum block architecture

Tags: blockchain, block-header, state-trie, merkle-patricia-tries, yellow-paper

Where can I find a description (preferably a diagram like below) showing the block structure in an Ethereum blockchain?

[image: Diagram showing how Bitcoin transactions can be verified]

<sup>Credits: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_network#/media/File:Bitcoinpaymentverification.png)</sup>

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this is not only relevant to Proof of Work, the Proof of stake will still use the same Merkle Tree right?

Comment: @Cyberience yes, Merkle trees are still being used today (Sep 2023, post-Merge). But Merkle trees will be replaced by Verkle trees during [The Verge](https://twitter.com/milesdeutscher/status/1550315295402668032). Refer to this [blog post](https://ethereum.org/en/roadmap/verkle-trees/) for more info on Verkle trees.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Lets first start with my adaptation of [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_network#/media/File:Bitcoinpaymentverification.png) illustrating the Bitcoin block structure:

[image: Boitcoin Blockchain architecture]

So far so good. All fairly basic.

Enter Ethereum and things get a wee bit more complex. After reading through [this](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/) and [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Development-Tutorial), and as per @[eth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/42/eth) 's recommendation [this](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper), my best interpretation is the figure below:

[image: ![Ethereum Blockchain Architecture]

The header field definitions are available in section 4.3 of the [yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper).

Comment: Uncles is a hash (of a list of uncles), Yellow Paper has: "The Keccak 256-bit hash of the ommers list portion of this block".  Codehash is just a hash since contracts are immutable.  The pointers point to "hash of whole block header" (the Keccak-256 hash of all the bytes in the block header).  To have a full diagram, should really consult the Yellow Paper...

Comment: Updated response after consulting the YP. Starting to get clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: Why are the transactions from block N linked to those of block N+1?

Comment: These links correspond to contract state that has not changed in between blocks. Referencing the state from the previous blocks instead of replicating is more efficient from a block size perspective.

Comment: You forgot the difficulty in bitcoin headers.

Comment: Are new mined transactions included in the block as a 'reference' (e.g: only hash of previously broadcasted transaction in mempool) or is the transaction structure fully inlined in the block?  

If inlined/copied: there is some redundant data ineffeciency, right? once where transaction is broadcasted into mempool and then when copied to the block?  

If block transaction references mempool transaction: what happens if a node validating block has an unknown transaction? e.g: transaction is not in node mempool?

Answer (score 162):

Here's my interpretation, based on the yellow paper:

[image]

...the Tries should look more like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @atomh33ls, do you mind sharing the source file for the illustrations (in whatever software format you used to create them). I would like to create an illustration for transactions trie. It will look almost the same as state trie except some details will be changed. Thank you!

Comment: Explain them to us in simple english

Comment: @atomh33ls I would also be interested in the source files. I really like this amazing overview! What software did you use?

Comment: @atomh33ls +1 to the source file, please. If not, I'd also be happy recreating it in mermaid.js so the community could co-edit it. The three specific changes I have in mind are adding a note that the key size is shortened for simplified purposes, putting the tree complexity (max depth) in the bottom right, and adding and example of an extension node with prefix 1[].

Comment: @Olshansk The main diagram svg is [here](https://github.com/4c656554/BlockchainIllustrations/tree/master/Ethereum). Alas I don't have the merkle diagram to hand. They seem like good ideas - will be interesting to see what you come up with..

Comment: Has anyone dived into the details of whether there were changes to this after "the merge"?

Comment: @Olshansky the first diagram definitely requires an update after The Merge. Uncle blocks are now called [dunkles](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/19146/24693). Also, these diagrams will become increasingly outdated as Ethereum transitions to [The Surge, The Verge, The Purge, and eventually The Purge](https://twitter.com/milesdeutscher/status/1550315295402668032).

Answer (score 24):

Here is a complete structure of a block and where it plays its role in Ethereum's blockchain.

[image: Ethereum Block Structure]

You asked for a diagram but i think this would be more explanatory.

Answer (score 12):

The description can be found in the [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) which is the formal specification of the Ethereum protocol.

Here are the main pieces of a block:

> 4.3. The Block. The block in Ethereum is the collection of relevant pieces of information (known as the block header), H, together with
>   information corresponding to the comprised transactions, T, and a set
>   of other block headers U that are known to have a parent equal to the
>   present block’s parent’s parent.

No diagram though (an opportunity for the community).

Comment: ComeonI though you guys would do better at this explanation

Answer (score 10):

Here's a picture from V's article regarding data structures for light clients:

https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/02/18/ethereum-scalability-and-decentralization-updates/

[image]

Comment: The above is an abstraction of a Merkle tree. I'm rather looking for the Ethereum block structure (including all the actual header fields).

Answer (score 10):

Vitalik Buterin gives a compact answer:

Every block header in Ethereum contains 3 trees for three kinds of objects:
Transactions, Receipts (essentially, pieces of data showing the effect of each transaction), State.

You can read a longer version with pictures [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/).

Answer (score 6):

Extrapolating from the syntactic block structure, we can also ask what the semantic ethereum world state structure looks like. I use this diagram to explain the relationship between "on-chain", "off-chain", and everything in between, including L2 scaling solutions. Please see my accompanying [blog post](https://samlaf.github.io/blockchain/graphical-depiction-of-ethereum-scaling-solutions.html) for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my interpretation based on the latest version of yellow paper(BERLIN VERSION beacfbd – 2022-10-24)

[image]

here is the whole link: https://medium.com/@JanessaTech/ethereum-a-latest-interpretation-of-yellow-paper-29ec14d05867