# How Ethereum confirm the transaction?

Tags: transactions, cryptography, confirmations

Am I right, that  Ethereum do it the same way as Bitcoin ([Bitcoin dev guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#p2pkh-script-validation)), and the only difference is that the Ethereum use it's own `OP_CODES`?

**UPD** I mean, what is the Ethereum's alternative for `<Sig> <PubKey> OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PubkeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the chain of ownership and UTXOs used in Bitcoin to identify which transactions are correctly formed and which are not, Ethereum uses an account model, and transactions are sent with ECDSA signatures that verify against that account. The 'state' of each account is kept track of, and the transactions are checked to see both that the signature verifies, and the state change triggered as a result of the transaction is valid (eg I can't send you 8000 ETH if I only have 10).

From the [Ethereum Docs](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html):

> Transactions contain:
>
> - the recipient of the message,
> - a signature identifying the sender and proving their intention to send the message via the blockchain to the recipient,
> - VALUE field - The amount of wei to transfer from the sender to the recipient,
> - an optional data field, which can contain the message sent to a contract,
> - a STARTGAS value, representing the maximum number of computational steps the transaction execution is allowed to take,
> - a GASPRICE value, representing the fee the sender is willing to pay for gas. One unit of gas corresponds to the execution of one atomic instruction, i.e., a computational step.

If you wanted to verify signatures, [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4kvaoz/ethereum_signed_message_and_transaction/) from axic might be the type of thing you were looking for:

> Check out https://github.com/ethereumjs/helpeth
>
> It has similar features:
>
> `signMessage <message>`
>
> `verifySig <hash> <sig>`
>
> `verifySigParams <hash> <r> <s> <v>`

Answer (score 0):

there is not **only one difference** but more, the difference is not about opcodes but deeper than that. Ethereum is based on a VM using a turing complete language and bitcoin use a limited stack-based scripting language. this is a long subject to discuss I recommend you to read this article to get the difference between bitcoin and Ethereum

[What are the differences between Bitcoin blockchain and Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/700/what-are-the-differences-between-bitcoin-blockchain-and-ethereum-blockchain)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yep, I know about turing complete and all the stuff. The question is only about confirming the transactions. Can you give and example of Ethereum's default script, which is responsible for the same thing as Bitcoin's `<Sig> <PubKey> OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PubkeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG` ?

Comment: Ethereum is different read the white paper it doesn't have Utxo so there is no locking unlocking script