# Why do transaction receipts not include the value of Ether transferred?

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain, ether, receipts

I'm writing some logic to identify the currency used in an ethereum transaction, and am wondering the following:

`web3.eth.getTransaction` returns a `value` field that indicates the value transferred in Wei.

However I'm using receipts, and `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` does not include the value transferred, which seems a little unintuitive. Why is this the case?

Comment: Often web3js tries to reflect the data as defined in the Yellow Paper, which doesn't include value in the receipt. It should be possible to write a method `getTransactionAndReceipt`, but it is kinda of subjective to include it in web3js or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receipts are basically for [proving logs and events](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/proving-the-existence-of-logs-to-the-blockchain), rather than details of a transaction.

In https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum
Vitalik Buterin gave an example of using receipts, as well as other examples that can be answered with Merkle proofs:

- Has this transaction been included in a particular block?
- Tell me all instances of an event of type X (eg. a crowdfunding contract reaching its goal) emitted by this address in the past 30 days
- What is the current balance of my account?
- Does this account exist?
- Pretend to run this transaction on this contract. What would the output be?

> The first is handled by the transaction tree; the third and fourth are
>   handled by the state tree, and the **second by the receipt tree**. The
>   first four are fairly straightforward to compute; the server simply
>   finds the object, fetches the Merkle branch (the list of hashes going
>   up from the object to the tree root) and replies back to the light
>   client with the branch.

Related:

- [What are Ethereum transaction receipts and what are they used for?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/what-are-ethereum-transaction-receipts-and-what-are-they-used-for)
- [Relationship between Transaction Trie and Receipts Trie](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/relationship-between-transaction-trie-and-receipts-trie)