# events can cause state change?

Tags: solidity, transactions, mining, events

I am doing a simple HelloWorld class trying out several things including emitting events. My contract code is below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract HelloWorld {
    string public myMessage = "Hello World!";

    event MessageReturned( string message );

    function setMessage( string memory newMessage ) external {
        myMessage = newMessage;
    }

    function getMessage() external view returns( string memory ) {
        return myMessage;
    }

    function sayMessage() external view {
        emit MessageReturned( myMessage );
    }
}
```

I got surprised I got a `TypeError` when I tried to compile with `truffle compile`. I received this message form `solc`:

```
TypeError: Function cannot be declared as view because this expression (potentially) modifies the state.
  --> project:/contracts/HelloWorld.sol:18:14:
   |
18 |         emit MessageReturned( myMessage );
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Could anyone please help explain to me why emitting an event is treated as a state change here? What goes behind the scenes to cause it to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1309/84305) might clarify it alongside [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5959/84305.).

In essence, transactions receipts (containing the logs) are used to form the Transaction Receipt Trie, which will update the Transaction Receipts Root that is recorded in the header of a block (a new block is essentially an update of the state of the blockchain).

Hence, emitting an event is indeed a state changing operation, so the `view` / `pure` visibility modifiers are forbidden. It's not that Events can cause state change, but more that events will cause state change.

Comment: I see, as I understand the reference above events are actually causing the EVM to log, which is an internal transaction. Thank you @hroussille