# What is the beneficiary in block header?

Tags: block-header

There is the data called "beneficiary" in block header. What is this data?

Comment: Please provide a link to an example block

Comment: "beneficiary" is in the figure image in following answer.

http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the image from the linked answer [Ethereum block architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture) provided in your comment.

[image]

And here's the data from a block [1932656](http://etherscan.io/block/1932656). Beneficiary in the image above is the `miner` in the data below. The Beneficiary receives the block reward of 5 ethers.

```
> eth.getBlock("latest")
{
  difficulty: 59542618611819,
  extraData: "0xd78301040a844765746887676f312e362e32856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 152778,
  hash: "0x8cb83abce49e0519517eb80f855f195484765c809bea8c7d5382031f763f9e5b",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000020000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000020000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0xbcdfc35b86bedf72f0cda046a3c16829a2ef41d1",
  nonce: "0xc8a0edd33d21e5ad",
  number: 1932656,
  parentHash: "0x02cf39cec15847646ddd6732ade2e28e8e863298047dd4d9ce063dbb995d4f40",
  receiptRoot: "0xb057e15fc6cae04608c91eb58510e26066d5c52abd56b6cf494d1a2ff3ccbc91",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 1286,
  stateRoot: "0x0f02a05b7dd3c11745cd03b69c35e3b1a0f678252abecf5fcac7386d19cc8da0",
  timestamp: 1469203461,
  totalDifficulty: 40241549278922643891,
  transactions: ["0x37ea70aa47f2fdd58aa4f0ad3a99b8c08848f2597eecd9c400762f86234becfe", "0x7b0a17a9e5db028ab6c5acd7aa4a61a5ae9b91f6ba917523aac413a454061385", "0xde92594f7329163325a508378e48cd64d9bf1ae5384d15c7847f79c2817d61b3", "0xce446d81af127eb8c67bc4f50572e73b72bdc37d2a2d87fbf06ba1dfd5c7da8a", "0x9c40ba3ee3960b5b7a534432aaa62fc5241458f8e28c36991cca168469d83f15", "0xf93ef96448178b1c963982c1a25a7b3136da728655091bc7c964c0cc2479ef79"],
  transactionsRoot: "0x4d43ebb736e55feddd5993219da2b2dc4984f7aad4b18637dfd90368dc8e64c5",
  uncles: []
}
```

Comment: So beneficiary is not correct, right? "miner" means the address of miner who receives the mining reward. Am I right?

Comment: Beneficiary is also correct.  The Yellow Paper tries to be more general, because when there's a move to something like Proof of Stake, "mining" and "miner" is less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The beneficiary field contains the 160-bit address of the recipient that
will receive the mining reward once the block is successfully mined.