# If you're a node, why would you accept other node's solution instead of copying and broadcasting that solution?

Tags: security

Let's say someone broadcasted a solution to the recent block. Why, as a node, would I accept it? I can just copy and broadcast it myself instead. Yes, most of the times the first node would win, but in rare occasions I would get ahead of that node (mine would propagate faster) and get the reward, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could. But you would not get the reward.

The mining reward receiver is added inside the block as `beneficiary` (or `miner`) and therefore you can't change that without remining the block. Here's some more info: [What is the beneficiary in block header?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/what-is-the-beneficiary-in-block-header)

Comment: Can't we just change the `beneficiary` to ourselves?

Comment: As I said in my answer you can't change it without invalidating the block. Any change in the block data results in a different hash value and the new value does not meet the mining target anymore, so you would have to solve the mining puzzle again