# Are there still uncles with proof-of-stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, uncle-blocks

As I understand, with PoS the selected validator is determined within predictable time windows. Does this mean that uncles will be gone for PoS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it stands, by my reading of it, there is something akin to uncles in the proposed PoS system, referred to as "dunkles". See [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ):

> The second strategy is to simply punish validators for creating blocks
>   on the wrong chain. That is, if there are two competing chains, A and
>   B, then if a validator creates a block on B, they get a reward of +R
>   on B, but the block header can be included into A (in Casper this is
>   called a "dunkle")

And from the (possibly superceded) [mauve paper by Vitalik Buterin](https://web.archive.org/web/20161102091308/http://vitalik.ca/files/mauve_paper3.html):

> The purpose of the "dunkle" mechanism is to solve the "nothing at
>   stake" problem in proof of stake, where if there are no penalties but
>   only rewards then validators are incentivized to try to make blocks on
>   top of every possible chain.

If a validator bets on a block that doesn't make it into the chain (a dunkle), then they will suffer a penalty when the dunkle's header is included in a future valid block (with a reward paid to the validator that includes it).