# Block header format

Tags: blocks, leveldb, block-header, rlp

Does anyone understand what each element of a block header represents? I have an example block header represented here:

[

cd7bd64fba4cc782fe5474d3640882afece5887180591e72f80ce6916cf73526,

1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347,

f927a40c8b7f6e07c5af7fa2155b4864a4112b13,

30430d24554454b251003be3d027dea94397bf45cd34c6a06abcfec662242046,

56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421,

56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421,

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,

3b32b8463f,

1780,

1388,

"",

55ba9f2d,

"Geth/v1.0.0/linux/go1.4.2",

437fa41b15c73334a947241ec885423a487d4401a0c3ec7c30550c1e039bccd7,

c5317acb884dfc49,

]

What do each of these elements represent? Is there an official source that also definitively says what each of these values mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture

Comment: Thanks @Andromelus, I believe this article is useful, but I don't believe I can derive what each of these values are from this post. I was hoping for a little more clarity about what each of these values represent. This article provides a pool of values that might apply to each of these but I do not know which order or which calculations to perform on them such as the date to get these values: Prev Hash, Nonce, Timestamp, Uncles Hash, Beneficiary, Logs Bloom, Difficulty, Extra data, Block Num, Gas Limit, Gas Used, MIx Hash, State Root, Transaction Root, Receipt Root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-blockchain-third-edition/9781839213199)

> - Parent hash: This is the Keccak 256-bit hash of the parent (previous) block's header.
>
> • Ommers hash: This is the Keccak 256-bit hash of the list of ommers
> (or uncles) blocks included in the block.
>
> • The beneficiary: The beneficiary field contains the 160-bit address
> of the recipient that will receive the mining reward once the block is
> successfully mined.
>
> • State root: The state root field contains the Keccak 256-bit hash of
> the root node of the state trie. It is calculated once all
> transactions have been processed and finalized.
>
> • Transactions root: The transaction root is the Keccak 256-bit hash
> of the root node of the transaction trie. The transaction trie
> represents the list of transactions included in the block.
>
> • Receipts root: The receipts root is the Keccak 256-bit hash of the
> root node of the transaction receipt trie. This trie is composed of
> receipts of all transactions included in the block. Transaction
> receipts are generated after each transaction is processed and contain
> useful post-transaction information. More details on transaction
> receipts are provided in the next section.
>
> • Logs bloom: The logs bloom is a bloom filter that is composed of the
> logger address and log topics from the log entry of each transaction
> receipt of the included transaction list in the block. Logging is
> explained in detail in the next section.
>
> - Logs bloom: The logs bloom is a bloom filter that is composed of the logger address and log topics from the log entry of each transaction
>   receipt of the included transaction list in the block. Logging is
>   explained in detail in the next section.
>
> • Difficulty: The difficulty level of the current block.
>
> • Number: The total number of all previous blocks; the genesis block
> is block zero.
>
> • Gas limit: This field contains the value that represents the limit
> set on the gas consumption per block.
>
> • Gas used: This field contains the total gas consumed by the
> transactions included in the block.
>
> • Timestamp: The timestamp is the epoch Unix time of the time of block
> initialization.
>
> - Extra data: The extra data field can be used to store arbitrary data related to the block. Only up to 32 bytes are allowed in this field.
>
> • Mixhash: The mixhash field contains a 256-bit hash that, once
> combined with the nonce, is used to prove that adequate computational
> effort (Proof of Work, or PoW) has been spent in order to create this
> block.
>
> • Nonce: Nonce is a 64-bit hash (a number) that is used to prove, in
> combination with the mixhash field, that adequate computational effort
> (PoW) has been spent in order to create this block.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can find the block header's structure in the  [Yellow paper, **4.4**  (page 5)](http://yellowpaper.io).

I don't have time to go through eveyrthing, but if I do not make any mistake, for example, you could bind the following:

> cd7bd64fba4cc782fe5474d3640882afece5887180591e72f80ce6916cf73526 --> Parent hash
>
> 1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347 --> ommersHash
>
> f927a40c8b7f6e07c5af7fa2155b4864a4112b13 --> beneficiary
>
> 30430d24554454b251003be3d027dea94397bf45cd34c6a06abcfec662242046 --> stateRoot
>
> 56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421 --> transactionsRoot
>
> 56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421 --> receiptsRoot
>
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 --> logsBloom
>
> 3b32b8463f --> difficulty
>
> 1780 --> Number of ancestor blocks
>
> 1388 --> gasLimit
>
> "" --> gasUsed
>
> 55ba9f2d --> timestamp
>
> "Geth/v1.0.0/linux/go1.4.2" --> ExtraData
>
> 437fa41b15c73334a947241ec885423a487d4401a0c3ec7c30550c1e039bccd7 --> mixHash
>
> c5317acb884dfc49 --> nonce

From what I read of your example, this matches pretty well.