# Is Ethereum block header a list?

Tags: blocks, encoding, rlp, block-header, decoding

Decoding a RLP encoded block using Eth specifications do we get header as list? But as per format i.e., [[blockHeader,transactionList,uncleList],totalDifficulty], blockHeader should have been string.

Attaching Encoded Block below

```
17f902ccf902c8f90258a0a5e6ce19d2977e762e455309f31971edbe3
46172b5f869f9193bea18cdb29520a01dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6
ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d493479400000000000000000
00000000000000000000000a0ff0cb4f1ba9acef7d1b8469a0637ab8a
bf65c88dee1685a0bb7fbbd565c3e921a0cf9084fc1c24adb33aa1c1c
ca7fdf06700931c6eae3a7a52d1512c81afd83d0fa0056b23fbba4806
96b65fe5a59b8f2148a1299103c4f57df839233af2cf4ca2d2b901000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
01835ff7a7825208845df9fcfcb861d883010906846765746888676f3
12e31312e31856c696e7578000000000000008e5bd5d89fa09223dfd1
39abcdee95225416eca1a5363c00def8a2cedfce88f733c88adbefa18
3c107336bb2aa4cf8e0ebef8db2957fbe41fa6d8b7517d2b4f901a000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000880000000000000000f86af86880018252089473aa7daa1378e5
33c3909f8a69b3296ae9f5fe4c87b1a2bc2ec5000080820a96a00ae79
1d21f7f5b87e52da210fb653e4c2b8562380bf7b18500b33efb24e2c4
3aa02b15fdd44e6ad1a52a93770b4916e3c94759c600982f6a232689e
e2669aaa062
```

Comment: first byte(17) is message type. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31314/block-header-format. As per attached link, Block header is list.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the go implementation of the header struct [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/b6d4f6b66e99c08f419e6a469259cbde1c8b0582/core/types/block.go#L70). It could be implemented in different languages differently depending on the corresponding programming patterns. However it should match the specs in the [Ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).