# State tree diagram with real world ethereum transaction

Tags: blockchain

Newbee here. Just getting used to StackExchange interface and protocol. Apologies up front for any feeling of misgiving.

Would anyone be able to provide an ethereum state trie diagram depicting how an ethereum transaction gets stored in the state trie?

@atom33ls provided [an example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6413/16301) in the question thread [Ethereum Block Architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture), but I'm still a little confused. The diagram provided has a Simplified World State key-value mapping table, top right corner. This is a great diagram but I'm confused by the table. I don't quite understand how the keys are derived? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with [Merkle Patricia Tree](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree). If you go through article you will find 4 different types of node:

- `NULL` (represented as the empty string)
- `branch` A 17-item node `[ v0 ... v15, vt ]`
- `leaf` A 2-item node `[ encodedPath, value ]`
- `extension` A 2-item node `[ encodedPath, key ]`

From the keys in the diagram you can trace the path through shared nibbles in extension nodes, positions in the branch nodes and so on until you reach key-end.

Hope that will help!

Comment: Yes, I've reviewed the paper in your response. I must be a dumb dumb because I'm still lost. Arghh..