# Where I can I find a description of how geth maps Blocks, Transactions, Accounts, etc. onto a LevelDB database

Tags: go-ethereum, leveldb

Where I can I find a description of how geth maps Blocks, Transactions, Accounts, etc. onto a LevelDB database? I can dump the 300+ million db blocks (keys) in my local geth database but I have no idea how to parse them beyond that.

Thank you,
Michael Herman

p.s. That is, something that maps [Ethereum block architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture) into LevelUp constructs/API calls.

Comment: So are you curious where the information of Ethereum is stored in a levelDB? How it is stored?