# What is saved on every block on Ethereum?

Tags: blocks, bitcoin

In Bitcoin every block has the information about the transaction (A sends money to B, C to D etc). And everytime a new transaction (someone sends money to another address) is sent, the miners will create a new block (or add to the new one).
**What is saved in Ethereum?**
I guess if we are sending ETH to some address, then the same data (A transfers ETH to B) is saved, but I guess Ethereum is saving more data too, because of the smart contracts.
So what data is saved in Ethereum? and when is created a new block in Ethereum? (in Bitcoin a new block is created every 10 minutes and it includes the transactions from one address to another one registered by the minner who discovered the nonce).

Not sure if this questions makes sense :(

Comment: read the yellow/white paper

Comment: the point of sites like this is to leave a reply, to help people with the same question in an easier and faster way. With your criteria if someone asks how to do something in PHP we should just reply "read a book about PHP"? nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for are ALL in the yellow/white paper, it would take too long to explain everything here and its already explained in the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

A block, exactly like in bitcoin, contains all the transaction that has been mined for this block.

It contains informations like:

1. Parent hash
2. stateRoot
3. difficulty
4. number
5. ...

And of course the transactions.

AS it is explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture) , [here](https://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/quickBlocks/blob/develop/src/other/presentations/Data%2C%20Data%2C%20Data.pdf)

For exact details: go check the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

---

Edit: You can find an example of what a block looks like using web3js or any library that allows to interact with the chain: check [this function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getBlock#getblock)

---

Edit2: To answer the question in the comments:

Basically, a transaction is a transfer of 0 or more ETH from address A to address B. The transaction can also contain data. 
If the transaction is not an ETH transfer but a function call to a smart contract, the "to" parameter is the contract address and the "value" param is 0. The function will use the data provided in the transaction. This data are mapped using the contract binary interface.

So, shortly, the block contains the transactions and the transactions contains all the information necessary to transfer ETH and/or* to execute a contract function.

*: A contract behaves like a "normal account", it can receive and own ETH and at the same time, execute a function

Comment: Thanks! I know I can find the answer in the white paper, but I was looking for something not so technical. I mean the "main info" the core functionality. In BTC we probably save a lot of things, but the main info is "moving BTC from addr to addr", so in Ethereum is saved on every block something like "call this function with these params in this smart contract"? and also "create a smart contract with this code"?

Comment: @Enrique I updated the answer for you. I hope it is clear enough. The topic is very big and it is hard to talk about something without mentionning something else :S