# Ethereum Blockchain Size calculation from Etherscan

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, blocks, statistics

I was looking into Etherscan.io charts of Ethereum Block Count and Ethereum Average Block Size. Both of them have the data since 07/30/2015 and if one multiply both time-series

(Ex. 07/30/2015 - 644 Byte Blocksize * 6912 Total Blocks of the day =  4451328 (0.004451328 GB) added to the Blockchain.

All the way up to 07/08/2018, Total Blockchain size comes out to around 47 GB size of the Blockchain. Looks like I am missing something major here as the current Ethereum Blockchain size is almost 1TB.

Any help into what I am missing would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not have a local copy of the Ethereum blockchain, and so I cannot confirm it, but apart of the blockchain (i.e. blocks and transactions) a full node stores also the world state, i.e. a big merkle patricia tree containing the state of all the accounts, as shown here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture/757#757. Maybe you forgot this giant datastructure

Comment: Thanks Briomez for the reply. You are right as I did not include the world state in my calculation. 

Is there anywhere we can find the details on the world state apart from local copy of the Ethereum blockchain? 

I am trying to model the size of the Blockchain for max 1 year and min 1 month, based on the current state.