# Verifiyng value in contract

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, network

Imagine a network where only specific nodes have ether and can run contracts, and there are other nodes, lets call then **V**, that only want to read the content produced by the other nodes.

Is there a way for **V** nodes to check the values in a specific contract without having ether?

Comment: You could run a full node and look at the state of the blockchain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to read the content of the storage without ether.

### Premise

Each peer of the network has a local copy of the entire blockchain and of the state, therefore also of each contract's storage. You can get more details [in this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/757).

### Concretely

One can read the *raw data* contained in a contract's storage with the web3 API function [eth.getStorageAt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetstorageat).

To facilitate the read of the data (with a pre-defined interface) one can write solidity functions marked as `view` (i.e., they promise not to modify the state) and `public` (i.e., they can be called with a tx). With the web3 API you can call this type of functions locally without a transaction.